# Updating persons in database with newly created addresses

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have the following code, and I'd like to refactor it to a more functional way:

```
public void processPersons(List<Person> personList) {
    for (Person person : personList) {
        Integer addressId = createAddress(person);
        if (addressId != null) {
            updateDbStatus(addressId, person);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I convert the above to a more functional style of programming?

Comment: Use *method references* to shorten your `map()`

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Comment: CodeReview is basically for working code. In your question, it's not a working code. Half-written, so that's the reason why it has been mentioned as off-topic

Comment: Okay, so if I added a method around the code and provided the createAddress and updateDbStatus (which I left out intentionally, since their implementation is not really part of the problem), then it would have been fine?

Comment: I think you didn't still get it. The problem is, `.... // I need the person and the addressId here....` that part. CodeReview is to improve the working code. If you don't know how to write it the rest, then this question needs to be asked in StackOverflow. But if you were able to write the rest of the, and it is working fine, then this question is suitable here

Comment: Well, I can remove that part, and say: "how can I refactor this code into functional code?". The code is working in my example, that's the first part of the code. The second part is there to show that I tried something, and didn't just put some code here for others to refactor. I had a similar question on SO, and they pointed me to CodeReview. It's quite ironic that now you point me back.

Comment: I've removed the 'nonworking' code, and only left the working code. Is it still offtopic?

Comment: The question still lacks context for a review. What does the code for `createAddress()` look like?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan That seems to have been an attempt at refactoring the code, but the attempt failed. That doesn't make the original code non-working or off-topic.

Comment: @200_success I disagree that the `createAddress()` implementation is necessary here.

Comment: You can probably rewrite your code like this `personList.forEach(person -> Optional.ofNullable(createAddress(person)).ifPresent(addressId -> updateDbStatus(addressId, person)));` , but I wouldn't recommend it. The code you have now is better in my opinion.

Comment: @200_success why do you think that part is important? It might call a REST endpoint, it might generate a random int without doing anything, whatever it is, it shouldn't affect this refactoring.

Comment: You haven't told us what it does. It is possible that the best refactoring involves modifying `createAddress()`.

Answer (score 3):

One of variants is to have `PersonWithAddress` subclass with created `addressIp`:

```
    persons
            .stream()
            .map(PersonWithAddress::new)
            .forEach(this::updateDbStatus);
```

You call `updateDbStatus` where check the address for `null`:

```
void updateDbStatus(PersonWithAddress personWithAddress) {
    if (personWithAddress.getAddressIp() != null) {
        // do the update
    }
}
```

Model classes like these ones:

```
class Person{
    Person(final Person original) {
        // copy constructor
    }
}

class PersonWithAddress extends Person {
    private final Integer addressIp;

    PersonWithAddress(final Person person) {
        super(person);
        this.addressIp = createAddress();
    }

    Integer getAddressIp() {
        return addressIp;
    }

    private Integer createAddress() {
        // have a logic to create an address
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had something similar (I just used a Pair/Tuple2), but I didn't think the end result was better than the code already in place.

Comment: @ErikPragt That might be an indication that the code you currently have isn't that bad after all.

Comment: @ErikPragt this answer is most helpful, so flag it. beside that we can't see your answer yet!

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with Java 8, you'd be happy to explore the other features in it like `Optional<T>`

You can change your `createAddress()` to return an Optional which will be more expressive.

```
Optional<Person> createAddress(person){
   //write your logic and return the result wrapped in an Optional
}
```

As `addressId` has *one-to-one mapping with Person*, you should add an identifier to the Person class to hold the `addressId`. Then you have to modify the method signature of updateDbStatus as `updateDbStatus(Person person)`

```
class SomeClass{

 void someMethod(){

   personList.stream()
    .map(SomeClass::createAddress)
    .ifPresent(SomeClass::updateDbStatus)
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jude, but this won't really fix the issue, because the updatDbStatus still needs the person and the addressId. There is no one-to-one mapping between these classes.